# python google cloud function local dependency

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, package

I am writing two google cloud functions in python. These two functions have some common code. This is my directory tree:

```
root
|-- module
    |-- common
        |-- common_func.py
    |-- func1
        |-- main.py
        |-- requriments.txt
    |-- func2
        |-- main.py
        |-- requriments.txt
```

In `commmon_func.py` i have a method `common_method()` used in both `main.py` (corresponding to each cloud function). Locally works fine making the following import:

```
from root.module.common.common_func import common_method
```

but when deploying into google cloud functions, this does not work, im assuming somehow in the `requirements.txt` i need to specify to ship the `common_func` module.

How can i achieve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to share code between two different cloud functions as each one resides on a different VM. There are two ways to achieve what you want to do:

1. Create a package that contains all the requirements and upload it (you had to add the source code of the common function twice one for each function)
2. Make use of an external repository, for example I recreated your environment and call the dependences by calling the repository on the `requirements.txt` file.

For example I imported the name of a variable from an external repository:

`requirements.txt` file

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/project_name/r/repository_name
```

`main.py` file

```
from package_name import class_name

def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return class.menssage
```

And in this way you can change the common module on your code by uploading to a repository